# How to integrate cscope with vim on Windows?

Tags: windows, vim, cscope

vim version : 7.1
echo has ('cscope') : 1

I am trying to integrate cscope environment with vim on windows. 
I am trying to create a new database through the following command

cscope add C:\Path

I get the error message 
E563: stat(C:\Path) error:2

I assume the error message is because cscope is unable to create the database file 
needed by it to perform it's operations. The path provided is a valid path.

What could be the possible reason for the following error ?

Thanks
Gudge

Answer (score 2):

Just to validate how you set it up ...

1. Create the cscope database:

   C:\Tools\src>c:\tools\bin\cscope.exe -bv .*.c .*.h

   Generating Database ...
2. Next you need to set the path to the cscope executible inside vim:

   se csprg=C:\tools\bin\csope.exe
3. Then add the path (properly escaped) to your cscope database:

   cs add C:\tools\src\
4. Now you should be able to use cscope just fine.

Note that I used vim 7.3.470 from the Cream site and my cscope is the native Win32 version hosted at Google code.

Comment: It didn't work for me at step 3 until I removed the trailing backslash. "cs add C:\tools\src"

Comment: Found this page again and now only ":cs add c:\tools\src\scope.out" worked.

Comment: thank you for the `win32 version hosted at google code`. I'm looking for an binary version.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the error message is that you don't have a cscope database at all.

In order to be able to do a successful `:cs add`, you have to **build the database before you try to add it.**

An example for building the database could be found in this Vim Tip:
[Automatically create and update cscope database](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_create_and_update_cscope_database)

Once you built the database (say at C:/temp/cscope.out), you could open the connection to the database using `:cs add C:/temp/cscope.out`

Comment: For me when I try to add the `-C` switch (case insensitive) while adding the database I get a stat error, which reads `E563: stat(/dbc/blr-dbc202/AJ/CSCOPE_DB/CSCOPE_KERNEL_MAIN/cscope.out) error: 2` however when I add it without the `-C` option, it gets added. Secondly, it gets autoloaded when I invoke it from within the same directory like so: `/usr/bin/cscope -dl -f cscope.out`. So if I try to add it with the `-C` switch again (from within VIM) it doesn't allow me. Could you help?

Comment: @HighOnMeat: sorry, no clue. Maybe ask an own question for this.